# Simple Firebase Data retrieval

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm just trying to perform a simple firebase data retrieval. Here's what I have

```
var fb = new Firebase("https://<my-app>.firebaseio.com");

fb.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var db = snapshot.val();
  var speed = db['speed'];
 });

console.log(speed);

rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * 7 );
fb.set({ speed: rnd});
```

The problem I have is speed is stuck inside of the fb.on area. How do I get it out of there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't getting stuck, you're calling it incorrectly.

```
fb.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var db = snapshot.val();
  var speed = db['speed'];
});
```

Here you're providing a callback function with a local variable `speed`. This variable will probably be set correctly, but you're not doing anything with it.

```
console.log(speed);

rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * 7 );
fb.set({ speed: rnd});
```

This code runs straight after you've set up the event handler (`fb.on( 'value', ... )`) but that code runs asynchronously. Not only will that function probably not have ran at this point, but here you are accessing an undeclared variable `speed`, and because it isn't declared it is an automatic global variable `window.speed`, and not the local variable `speed` in the callback function.

Move the `console.log` inside of the callback function to execute it at the right time. Also, always declare your variables.